# waiting for all asynchronous web service calls to return

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have a desktop app (.net 3.5) which communicates with the server using classic web services.
I need to make numerous calls to web service functions, wait for them all to finish, and then proceed.

I'd like to do these calls in parallel; so obviously I'm looking to utilize the `MyFunctionAsync` method.
The thing is- i'm not sure how to verify that all calls have returned. I'm probably missing some simple synchronization mechanism here.

here's what i'd like to be able to do:

```
public void DoWork()
{
   service.MyFuncCompleted+= MyFunc_Completed;
   foreach (var i in items)
   {
      service.MyFuncAsync(i);
      syncMechanism.WaitForAnother(1);  //signal that we have to wait for 1 more task to finish
   }
   syncMechanism.WaitForAllTasksToFinsih();  //wait until specified number of tasks have finished

   //continue
}

public void MyFunc_Completed(EventArgs e)
{
   //process result...
   syncMechanism.Signal(1);  //signal that 1 task has finished
}
```

anybody know anything like this is c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ( fork / join ) is a lot easier in .NET 4, but you're on 3.5 so you'll have to do it the old-fashioned way.

Basically, increment a counter for each operation and then decrement it in your `Completed` handler. Then check if it's got down to zero and if so signal a wait handle to indicate all operations have completed.

Here's an example of the idea:

```
static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent( false );
static int inFlight = 1; // start with 1 to fix race condition

static void DoWork()
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

        Interlocked.Increment( ref inFlight );

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    if ( Interlocked.Decrement( ref inFlight ) == 0 ) mre.Set();

    mre.WaitOne(); // this blocks until all workers have completed
}

static void bw_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
{
    Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
}

static void bw_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
{
    if ( Interlocked.Decrement( ref inFlight ) == 0 ) mre.Set();
}
```

Comment: "check if it's got down to zero" : how would you suggest doing that? busy-wait? `(while (true) { if (counter == 0) break; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a simple counter I would use an hashmap, where the key is the thread-id (or the webservice name, or whatever you can find easy to handle).

As a value use a string or an object (representing the invocation time).

When a given call returns, remove the corresponding item from the hashmap.

When the hashmap is empty, you know you can proceed.
If it is not empty after a long time (which is basically a timeout for the collection of calls you made) you can check inside the hashmap to see which one is still pending, and how long is it taking.

Alternatively, you can use a more sophisticated object as a value, and record, along with the original timestamp, the return code for those who failed (in this case you have a more complete information than just "it returned").